# How to read from a (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I used the google drive api to get a [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) of (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File) called files.

Then I used a loop and an if statement to get a text file.

```
foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Name.Equals("UTMIDS.txt"))
        {
            //read data from file
        }
    }
```

How to read from that file?!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) is doing is getting you a list of the meta data for the file on Google drive.   If you want to read the contence of the file you will need to download the file localy.

```
var fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
// Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
// It will notify on each chunk download and when the
// download is completed or failed.
request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
    (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
{
    switch(progress.Status)
    {
        case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
        {
            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
            break;
        }
        case DownloadStatus.Completed:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
            break;
        }
        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
            break;
        }
    }
};
request.Download(stream);
```

Code from [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

Comment: giving an error
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DriveService.Files'

Comment: driveService is the service that was created from the authentication process.  You will need to check your own code to figure out what the equivalent variable is.

Comment: Can a file be read from google drive, not only downloaded?